# People picker: Error - The user does not exist or is not unique

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, people-picker, user

I am using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise. I have configured the people picker with the following PowerShell command:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -url http://our.acc.myCompany.biz -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:gds.local,gds\-svc-fc-sp-upsync01,jShMJqHFIZn3D8;forest:domainjax.int.net,domainjax\pc_svc_sp2013_crawle,nBAlIcks3BMtO3p;domain:fcresources.local,fcresources\svc_sp_farm,DwhpGoPUBEOR7LOahJ9r;forest:ola1.cad.corp,ola1\SVC_spoint2013,sWu7epha;forest:yoyoamilk.com.ph,yoyoAMILK\svc_sp_profile,iEY4BgEl9dX4KUGeS0fP;forest:AMCLGN.com,AMCLGN\svc_sp_profile,iEY4BgEl9dX4KUGeS0fP"

stsadm -o setproperty -url http://our.tmp.myCompany.biz -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:gds.local,gds\-svc-fc-sp-upsync01,jShMJqHFIZn3D8;forest:domainjax.int.net,domainjax\pc_svc_sp2013_crawle,nBAlIcks3BMtO3p;forest:ola1.cad.corp,ola1\SVC_spoint2013,sWu7epha"

stsadm -o setproperty -url http://our.myCompany.biz -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:gds.local,gds\-svc-fc-sp-upsync01,jShMJqHFIZn3D8;forest:domainjax.int.net,domainjax\pc_svc_sp2013_crawle,nBAlIcks3BMtO3p;domain:fcresources.local,fcresources\svc_sp_farm,DwhpGoPUBEOR7LOahJ9r;domain:yoyoamilk.com.ph,yoyoAMILK\svc_sp_profile,iEY4BgEl9dX4KUGeS0fP"

stsadm -o setproperty -url http://our.myCompany.biz -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:gds.local,gds\-svc-fc-sp-upsync01,jShMJqHFIZn3D8;forest:domainjax.int.net,domainjax\pc_svc_sp2013_crawle,nBAlIcks3BMtO3p;domain:fcresources.local,fcresources\svc_sp_farm,DwhpGoPUBEOR7LOahJ9r;forest:ola1.cad.corp,ola1\SVC_spoint2013,sWu7epha;domain:yoyoamilk.com.ph,yoyoAMILK\svc_sp_profile,iEY4BgEl9dX4KUGeS0fP;forest:AMCLGN.com,AMCLGN\svc_sp_profile,iEY4BgEl9dX4KUGeS0fP"

stsadm -o setproperty -url http://our.acc.myCompany.biz -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:gds.local,gds\-svc-fc-sp-upsync01,jShMJqHFIZn3D8;forest:domainjax.int.net,domainjax\pc_svc_sp2013_crawle,nBAlIcks3BMtO3p;domain:fcresources.local,fcresources\svc_spa_farm,gkMJurj86OZItc5CHD44;domain:yoyoamilk.com.ph,yoyoAMILK\svc_sp_profile,iEY4BgEl9dX4KUGeS0fP"

stsadm.exe -o getproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -url http://our.acc.myCompany.biz 

stsadm.exe -o getproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -url http://our.myCompany.biz 



stsadm.exe -o setapppassword -password DwhpGoPUBEOR7LOahJ9r

stsadm -o setproperty -url http://our.myCompany.biz -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:gds.local,gds\-svc-fc-sp-upsync01,jShMJqHFIZn3D8;forest:domainjax.int.net,domainjax\pc_svc_sp2013_crawle,nBAlIcks3BMtO3p;domain:fcresources.local,fcresources\svc_sp_farm,DwhpGoPUBEOR7LOahJ9"
```

The people picker is working now with all the domains. I have now only one problem. When I go to the permissions page of a list, site or whatever and try to give some user permission it gives me an error. The user is comming from this domain: "domainjax".

I've got thiss error in de GUI:

[image]

In the ULS log I found this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The user does not exist
>   or is not unique.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.UpdateMembers(String
>   bstrUrl, UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId,
>   Int32 lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object&
>   pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object&
>   pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean
>   bSendEmail)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl,
>   UInt32 dwObjectType, String bstrObjId, Guid& pguidScopeId, Int32
>   lGroupID, Int32 lGroupOwnerId, Object& pvarArrayAdd, Object&
>   pvarArrayAddIds, Object& pvarArrayLoginsRemove, Object&
>   pvarArrayIdsRemove, Boolean bRemoveFromCurrentScopeOnly, Boolean
>   bSendEmail)

I try to add another user from the same domain and it is working fine. Can someone tell me what the problem is? Maybe in Active Directory in the user account?

UPDATE:

When I go to some sitecollection to the hidden userlist I can found the useraccount:

http://myCompany.com/disciplines/100000/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx

Why this user is not available in this hidden list and why this user gives this error when I try to give him permissions.

Answer (score 3):

same error and similar issue, its for 2010 but the solutions should still work!

The error lie's within active directory user, as other users from the same or other domains work.

saying this, there could be another problem... do you have a root site?

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The user does not exist
>   or is not unique.
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.UpdateMembers(String
>   bstrUrl, …
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateMembers(String bstrUrl, …
>
> **Cause:**
>
> The Duet Claims Provider, like most SharePoint functionality, requires
>   a root site collection. The error "ServiceContext for the
>   `http://sharepointserver:port/` context is null" means that a root site
>   collection could not be found.
>
> For more information about limitations and supportability when no root
>   site collection exists for your SharePoint Web Application, see the
>   following articles:
>
> SharePoint 2010: Supportability of unprovisioned root site in a
>   SharePoint web application
>
> SharePoint: Office client integration errors when no root site exists
>
> Error message when you try to access a UNC Path of a Windows
>   SharePoint Services 3.0 or in SharePoint Server 2007 if no site
>   collection is mapped to the root of the web application: "The network
>   path was not found"
>
> **Resolution:**
>
> You can confirm if a root site collection exists by navigating to the
>   `http://sharepointserver:port/` site in a browser and then see if a
>   SharePoint site is displayed.  If there is no site at that URL, then
>   you will need to create a SharePoint site collection at
>   `http://sharepointserver:port/` to resolve this issue. The site template
>   used to create the root site is not important and it can be a blank
>   site.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/duetsupport/archive/2012/10/09/quot-the-user-does-not-exist-or-is-not-unique-quot.aspx

Comment: I try this in the browser and is working fine: http://myUrlToTheSharePointWebapplication.com:80 and is working fine. or do I need to test the url of the sitecollection where I have this problem?

Comment: is it only for that user?

Comment: I have also try to add this user to the permissions of the root site collection and this is working. It looks like this issue is in some sub site collection. In this one it is working http://myCompany.com/discipline/100008 and here not http://myCompany.com/discipline/100007. These are 2 differant site collections.

Comment: yes only for this user. In a couple of site collection I can add this user to the permissions of the site collection, and in a couple of site collections not! These sharepoint environment is migrated from sp2010 to sp2013 by avepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this for a customer by running stsadm -o adduser on the SharePoint server. Through the Web interface the error remains but with stsadm it is possible to add the user to the appropriate group.

Answer (score 0):

KHA - try to fix this issue with browser compatibility, add main site to the list of compatible sites! actually this issue became after 9th IE!

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible this user has been deleted in Active Directory and re-created afterwards with the same username and group. The problem is that when a user is recreated with the same details (username, groups, ...), the SID is not the same!

This means that for SharePoint the old user with username domainjax\JohnDoe is not the same as the re-created username domainjax\JohnDoe.

In order to check this you need to compare the SID of the AD-account with the SID of the account in SharePoint. If these two SID's don't match, you have 2 different accounts. These two SID's must be the same in order for it to be the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Having 2 forests. and seeing same error if user exists in both like 'domaina\mike' and there is a 'domainb\mike' . I could find the 'domainb\mike' and click grant permissions or try to add the user to the group but nothing happens and in the log i see error like user is nounique..
But if you have 'domainb\steve' and there is no 'domaina\steve' SP adds 'domainb\steve' just fine.