# SharePoint users only with full control able to use custom form

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, permissions, custom-form

We have some custom forms in SharePoint site and only with the full control, users able to access those forms, otherwise, they are getting

> `this site has not been shared with you` error.

When I checked log I am seeing the error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The user does not exist
>   or is not unique., StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser.InitMember()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser..ctor(SPWeb web, SPSecurableObject scope,
>   String strIdentifier, Object[,] arrUsersData, UInt32 index, Int32
>   iByParamId, String strByParamSID, String strByParamEmail,
>   SPUserCollectionType userCollectionType, SPUserCollectionFlags ucf,
>   Boolean isSiteAuditor)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.GetByLoginNoThrow(String
>   loginName, SPUserCollectionFlags ucf)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureUser(String logonName)...

When I checked using my login, even without full control I am able to see and submit the forms.

Comment: What's the SharePoint version?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Comment: We have people picker control in my form and updating it on the page load. Will it cause any issue?

Comment: Yes, maybe! try to remove it and check :)

Comment: We can't remove it. Only production, we have this issue. And not for me, only for other users.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104804/people-picker-error-the-user-does-not-exist-or-is-not-unique